# Installing Fonts using NSIS

Tags: nsis

I am installing fonts in my setup application using:

```
Section "Fonts"
  SetOutPath "$FONTS"
  StrCpy $FONT_DIR $FONTS
    !insertmacro InstallTTFfont '..\FONTS\English\Arial.ttf'
    SendMessage ${HWND_BROADCAST} ${WM_FONTCHANGE} 0 0 /TIMEOUT=5000
SectionEnd
```

(I have included !include FontReg.nsh and !include FontName.nsh)
At times, especially on Win 7(with UAC enabled), the setup progress goes into a non-reponsive mode(progress bar remains frozen at the end of the font installation and setup does not proceed). Is there anything to avoid this scenario?. Kindly help.

Thanks,
Bomzinho

Answer (score 0):

There is some macros dedicated for [registering fonts](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Register_Fonts) available on the NSIS wiki. They do a bit more than just copying the .ttf file.

Also you could look at the page on http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Advanced_Font_Installation